# Populating a dropdown list

Tags: pdo

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list to show the content field from my database but just getting a blank. Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong. It was suggested that i try going down this PDO route to prevent SQL injection.

Also, it seems that my previous posts have fallen foul of the sites code of practice pr some users aren't happy with my contribution - I'm not sure why so any advice on being a good community member would be appreciated.

Thanks, Mark

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Site Admin</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
require_once('connect.php');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetch();
?>



<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="null">Choose Page</option> 
  <?php
    foreach($results as $row) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $row['content'] ?>"><?= $row['content'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>
</select> 


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One way to make the question better is to tell us what is actually happening (weird behavior, error messages), including information you can get from the log. It's hard for us to just stare at the code without any context and any way to run it and just tell you what is wrong.

Comment: `"but just getting a blank"` - In PHP a blank page is often a sign of a critical error.  Turn on error reporting, check your PHP logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php'); //$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db', 'root', '');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];
?>

<?php
foreach($results as $row) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['content']; ?>"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></option>
<?php
} ?>
```